# How can I properly combine this queried data stored on a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I queried some historical exchange data for 3 currency pairs out of a RapidAPI repo by writing a POST request using Python (and doing so by running consecutive `for` iterative calls), and after that I placed it on a Pandas dataframe `df` getting the below data:

```
                                                                                                 historical      name
0  'Currency': 'USD', 'close': 1.1294, 'date': '03/01/2022', 'high': 1.1381, 'low': 1.1279, 'open': 1.1365,  EUR/USD
1  'Currency': 'USD', 'close': 1.1285, 'date': '04/01/2022', 'high': 1.1323, 'low': 1.1272, 'open': 1.1298,  EUR/USD
2  'Currency': 'USD', 'close': 1.1313, 'date': '05/01/2022', 'high': 1.1347, 'low': 1.1277, 'open': 1.1287,  EUR/USD
3  'Currency': 'USD', 'close': 1.1291, 'date': '06/01/2022', 'high': 1.1332, 'low': 1.1285, 'open': 1.1314,  EUR/USD
4  'Currency': 'USD', 'close': 1.1359, 'date': '07/01/2022', 'high': 1.1365, 'low': 1.1289, 'open': 1.1293,  EUR/USD
                                                                                                 historical      name
0  'Currency': 'CHF', 'close': 1.2381, 'date': '03/01/2022', 'high': 1.2392, 'low': 1.2312, 'open': 1.2345,  GBP/CHF
1  'Currency': 'CHF', 'close': 1.2388, 'date': '04/01/2022', 'high': 1.2415, 'low': 1.2356, 'open': 1.2386,  GBP/CHF
2  'Currency': 'CHF', 'close': 1.2426, 'date': '05/01/2022', 'high': 1.2459, 'low': 1.2377, 'open': 1.2398,  GBP/CHF
3  'Currency': 'CHF', 'close': 1.2461, 'date': '06/01/2022', 'high': 1.2483, 'low': 1.2399, 'open': 1.2431,  GBP/CHF
4  'Currency': 'CHF', 'close': 1.2482, 'date': '07/01/2022', 'high': 1.2507, 'low': 1.2456, 'open': 1.2465,  GBP/CHF
                                                                                                 historical      name
0  'Currency': 'CAD', 'close': 1.2741, 'date': '03/01/2022', 'high': 1.2780, 'low': 1.2629, 'open': 1.2634,  USD/CAD
1  'Currency': 'CAD', 'close': 1.2706, 'date': '04/01/2022', 'high': 1.2767, 'low': 1.2666, 'open': 1.2746,  USD/CAD
2  'Currency': 'CAD', 'close': 1.2752, 'date': '05/01/2022', 'high': 1.2767, 'low': 1.2691, 'open': 1.2707,  USD/CAD
3  'Currency': 'CAD', 'close': 1.2730, 'date': '06/01/2022', 'high': 1.2815, 'low': 1.2706, 'open': 1.2757,  USD/CAD
4  'Currency': 'CAD', 'close': 1.2644, 'date': '07/01/2022', 'high': 1.2733, 'low': 1.2631, 'open': 1.2733,  USD/CAD
```

But in order to make that data fully exportable to JSON file I would need to turn into something like this (or else only the last "block" of data -USD/CAD- ends up getting exported):

```
0  'Currency': 'USD', 'close': 1.1294, 'date': '03/01/2022', 'high': 1.1381, 'low': 1.1279, 'open': 1.1365, 'name': EUR/USD
1  'Currency': 'USD', 'close': 1.1285, 'date': '04/01/2022', 'high': 1.1323, 'low': 1.1272, 'open': 1.1298, 'name': EUR/USD
2  'Currency': 'USD', 'close': 1.1313, 'date': '05/01/2022', 'high': 1.1347, 'low': 1.1277, 'open': 1.1287, 'name': EUR/USD
3  'Currency': 'USD', 'close': 1.1291, 'date': '06/01/2022', 'high': 1.1332, 'low': 1.1285, 'open': 1.1314, 'name': EUR/USD
4  'Currency': 'USD', 'close': 1.1359, 'date': '07/01/2022', 'high': 1.1365, 'low': 1.1289, 'open': 1.1293, 'name': EUR/USD
5  'Currency': 'CHF', 'close': 1.2381, 'date': '03/01/2022', 'high': 1.2392, 'low': 1.2312, 'open': 1.2345, 'name': GBP/CHF
6  'Currency': 'CHF', 'close': 1.2388, 'date': '04/01/2022', 'high': 1.2415, 'low': 1.2356, 'open': 1.2386, 'name': GBP/CHF
7  'Currency': 'CHF', 'close': 1.2426, 'date': '05/01/2022', 'high': 1.2459, 'low': 1.2377, 'open': 1.2398, 'name': GBP/CHF
8  'Currency': 'CHF', 'close': 1.2461, 'date': '06/01/2022', 'high': 1.2483, 'low': 1.2399, 'open': 1.2431, 'name': GBP/CHF
9  'Currency': 'CHF', 'close': 1.2482, 'date': '07/01/2022', 'high': 1.2507, 'low': 1.2456, 'open': 1.2465, 'name': GBP/CHF
10  'Currency': 'CAD', 'close': 1.2741, 'date': '03/01/2022', 'high': 1.2780, 'low': 1.2629, 'open': 1.2634, 'name': USD/CAD
11  'Currency': 'CAD', 'close': 1.2706, 'date': '04/01/2022', 'high': 1.2767, 'low': 1.2666, 'open': 1.2746, 'name': USD/CAD
12  'Currency': 'CAD', 'close': 1.2752, 'date': '05/01/2022', 'high': 1.2767, 'low': 1.2691, 'open': 1.2707, 'name': USD/CAD
13  'Currency': 'CAD', 'close': 1.2730, 'date': '06/01/2022', 'high': 1.2815, 'low': 1.2706, 'open': 1.2757, 'name': USD/CAD
14  'Currency': 'CAD', 'close': 1.2644, 'date': '07/01/2022', 'high': 1.2733, 'low': 1.2631, 'open': 1.2733, 'name': USD/CAD
```

**OR** even better, something like this, if I can replace the useless `Currency` column by the `name` data and just call it `FX`:

```
0  'FX': 'EUR/USD', 'close': 1.1294, 'date': '03/01/2022', 'high': 1.1381, 'low': 1.1279, 'open': 1.1365
1  'FX': 'EUR/USD', 'close': 1.1285, 'date': '04/01/2022', 'high': 1.1323, 'low': 1.1272, 'open': 1.1298
2  'FX': 'EUR/USD', 'close': 1.1313, 'date': '05/01/2022', 'high': 1.1347, 'low': 1.1277, 'open': 1.1287
3  'FX': 'EUR/USD', 'close': 1.1291, 'date': '06/01/2022', 'high': 1.1332, 'low': 1.1285, 'open': 1.1314
4  'FX': 'EUR/USD', 'close': 1.1359, 'date': '07/01/2022', 'high': 1.1365, 'low': 1.1289, 'open': 1.1293
5  'FX': 'GBP/CHF', 'close': 1.2381, 'date': '03/01/2022', 'high': 1.2392, 'low': 1.2312, 'open': 1.2345
6  'FX': 'GBP/CHF', 'close': 1.2388, 'date': '04/01/2022', 'high': 1.2415, 'low': 1.2356, 'open': 1.2386
7  'FX': 'GBP/CHF', 'close': 1.2426, 'date': '05/01/2022', 'high': 1.2459, 'low': 1.2377, 'open': 1.2398
8  'FX': 'GBP/CHF', 'close': 1.2461, 'date': '06/01/2022', 'high': 1.2483, 'low': 1.2399, 'open': 1.2431
9  'FX': 'GBP/CHF', 'close': 1.2482, 'date': '07/01/2022', 'high': 1.2507, 'low': 1.2456, 'open': 1.2465
10  'FX': 'USD/CAD', 'close': 1.2741, 'date': '03/01/2022', 'high': 1.2780, 'low': 1.2629, 'open': 1.2634
11  'FX': 'USD/CAD', 'close': 1.2706, 'date': '04/01/2022', 'high': 1.2767, 'low': 1.2666, 'open': 1.2746
12  'FX': 'USD/CAD', 'close': 1.2752, 'date': '05/01/2022', 'high': 1.2767, 'low': 1.2691, 'open': 1.2707
13  'FX': 'USD/CAD', 'close': 1.2730, 'date': '06/01/2022', 'high': 1.2815, 'low': 1.2706, 'open': 1.2757
14  'FX': 'USD/CAD', 'close': 1.2644, 'date': '07/01/2022', 'high': 1.2733, 'low': 1.2631, 'open': 1.2733
```

Always keeping in mind that this process must run under a `for` iterative loop as the number of exchange pairs is TBD - it can be changed according to an user's needs.

I'm getting bogged down by this `name` piece that apparently is not stored as a string.

How can I get that done?

Thanks in advance,

Leonardo

Comment: Have you tried [pd.json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)? I find that's the easiest way to convert a list of objects into a dataframe. It's easier because you can do something like "remove name from every row" just by dropping the "name" column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED: to answer the question properly.

In light of our conversation in the comments, I've provided one possible solution. This will take the raw data provided by the response and transform it into a more readable JSON.

Each row of historical data is added to a list under a key which is the name of the conversion (e.g EUR/CAD)

for example, you would have:

`{'EUR/USD': [{'Currency': 'USD', 'close': 1.1126, 'date': '01/03/2022', 'high': 1.1234, 'low': 1.109, 'open': 1.1218}, {'Currency': 'USD', 'close': 1.1121, 'date': '02/03/2022', 'high': 1.1147, 'low': 1.1057, 'open': 1.1127}, {'Currency': 'USD', 'close': 1.1064, 'date': '03/03/2022', 'high': 1.1125, 'low': 1.1033, 'open': 1.1118}, {'Currency': 'USD', 'close': 1.0926, 'date': '04/03/2022', 'high': 1.1069, 'low': 1.0886, 'open': 1.1068}]}`

You can modify the code below so that every time a new batch of data is processed, the existing JSON file is loaded in and new rows are added to the data below.

This all depends on what your final intention is. Do you want a spreadsheet? Do you want to just have a store of JSON data? That will determine what your technique is for processing and storing the data.

```py
import json

import requests

url = "https://investing4.p.rapidapi.com/currencies/historical-data"
listofcurrencies = ["EUR%2FUSD","CAD%2FGBP"]
alldata = {}
itemnum = 0
for each in listofcurrencies:
    payload = 'to_date=04%2F03%2F2022&from_date=01%2F03%2F2022&interval=Daily&name={}'.format(each)
    print(payload)
    headers = {
            ALL YOUR RAPIDAPI DATA
    }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    js = response.json()
    alldata[js['data']['name']] = []
    for each in js['data']['historical']:
        alldata[js['data']['name']].append(each)

print(alldata)

with open("data.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(alldata, outfile)
```

Comment: I'll probably say things that will sound amateurish, but this is all fairly new to me...
To your question: when I print the POST request `response` object all it returns is the code 200.
But my code contains an additional line that converts `response` to a JSON format `data = response.json()`.
I then move `data` up one hierarchy level to get rid of the message status `data_list = data["data"]`.
I can't paste `data_list` in here, but I'm pretty sure it's in JSON. I only convert it to a Pandas df because it's the only way I know to convert to JSON with the correct orientation.

Comment: That's totally fine! What API are you using? I can test it on my own to figure out the structure of the data.

Comment: I took the `clean_data` from your code and added the following lines:
`jsonFile = open("data.json", "w")`
`jsonFile.write(clean_data)`
`jsonFile.close`
But I keep getting the error msg "write() argument must be str, not dict"

Comment: I'm using this API https://rapidapi.com/asepscareer/api/investing4/ If you go under "Currencies" and then to POST GetCurrencyHistoricalData you'll notice it only takes one batch of currency pair at a time, reason why I need to run this code recursively if I want to consider >1 pair of FX

Comment: Thanks Leo! I updated my answer after fooling with the API a bit. Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks a bunch buddy! Unfortunately I can't mark your answer as the one as I don't have enough reps, but your solution sure did work!

Comment: Ahh no problem! Glad it worked at least!